# How to cut an image into irregular shapes using objective c

Tags: ios

Thanks to everyone. I have got solution for cutting an image into irregular shapes in java. But now i want to achieved this in iOS.

Here is my requirement：

I am using fingers to select particular part by touch and draw on an image , after completing drawing, i want to draw that part of the image. I am able to draw using touches, but how can i cut that particular part?

i know cutting an image into rectangular  shape and circle but not into a particular shape.

If any one know please help me.

Comment: in this link solution our here :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943441/how-to-cut-an-image-into-irregular-shapes-using-objective-c

Answer (score 2):

Draw a closed CGPath and turn it into an Image Mask. If I had more experience I'd give more details, but I've only done the graphs in a weather app. A guide should help.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is the code for corp image with selected rectangle area. But you can customized your selected area with `CGPath` and then corp the image.

```
-(IBAction) cropImage:(id) sender{
    // Create rectangle that represents a cropped image  
    // from the middle of the existing image
    float xCo,yCo;
    float width=bottomCornerPoint.x-topCornerPoint.x;
    float height=bottomCornerPoint.y-topCornerPoint.y;
    if(width<0)
    width=-width;
    if(height<0)
    height=-height;

        if(topCornerPoint.x <bottomCornerPoint.x){
            xCo=topCornerPoint.x;
        }else{
            xCo=bottomCornerPoint.x;
        }

        if(topCornerPoint.y <bottomCornerPoint.y){
            yCo=topCornerPoint.y;
        }else{
            yCo=bottomCornerPoint.y;
        }

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(xCo,yCo,width,height);
    // Create bitmap image from original image data,
    // using rectangle to specify desired crop area
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"abc.png"];
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage], rect);
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef]; 
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    // Create and show the new image from bitmap data
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [imageView setFrame:CGRectMake(110, 600, width, height)];
    imageView.image=img;
    [[self view] addSubview:imageView];
    [imageView release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CGSize newSize = CGSizeMake(backGroundImageView.frame.size.width, backGroundImageView.frame.size.height);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize);

[<Drawing Imageview> drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];

[backGroundImageView.image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height) blendMode:kCGBlendModeSourceIn alpha:1.0];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Comment: Here Drawing Imageview is your Drawing Image on Which you are Drawing Irregular Shape.. This code is work for me. I Hope it may help you.